# Display Emoji icons in Mac app

Tags: macos, cocoa, emoji

I want the user to have easy access to Emoji icons in a small chat I am making for the company I'm working at.
Therefore, I want to make a panel which shows the available Emoji icons. To do this, I am using an `NSCollectionView`. Now, I need to pass a string which is shown in an `NSTextField`. This string must contain one Emoji icon.

I can't figure out how to write this Emoji icon in unicode in a string. Everything I have tried just shows a strange symbol instead of the icon.

Can anyone tell me, how I can put an Emoji icon into an `NSString`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want emoji ?

They're in Unicode now

If you open up the Character Viewer you can actually paste them directly into your source code.  If you'd rather, you can encode them in hexadecimal (`\U0001F431` for cat face) by looking them up in the Unicode code charts (especially the [chart for the U+1F300 block](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf)).

If you want to make sure they appear in color, you'll need to select the "Apple Color Emoji" font for the Emoji.  You can use [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsattributedstring_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to set the font on a per-character basis.